# jQuery show function applies inline-block sometimes and block others?

Tags: jquery, position, show-hide, css-position

I have a script right now where a certain element is shown and hidden often (similar to a tip).
I have noticed that sometimes the inline style says 'display: inline-block' and sometimes it says 'display: block'. The documentation as far as I can see only notes that it will use 'block'.

What appears to be happening, is it's using `display: inline-block` when the positioning is relative/static and is using `display: block` when the element is `position: fixed` but it sets this when the page is loaded and keeps it.

Therefore I have different behaviour if the page is loaded normally compared to if it's loaded while scrolled partway down, because a function applies a style with `position: fixed` when it's not in view (so that it will always be visible)

```
$(function() {  
    checkUrlEdit();

    $(window).scroll(function () { 
       checkUrlEdit();
    });

    $('a').hover( 
      function(){
        if(!editObj && !imageUpload){
            $('#urlEdit').show();
            $('#urlEdit').val($(this).attr('href'));}
    },
      function(){
        if(!editObj && !imageUpload){
        $('#urlEdit').hide();}
    } 
);

});

function checkUrlEdit(){
       if (!isScrolledIntoView('#urlEditor')) {
           $('#urlEdit').addClass('floating');

       } else {
           $('#urlEdit').removeClass('floating');
       }
}

function isScrolledIntoView(node)
{
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var nodeTop = $(node).offset().top;
    var nodeBottom = nodeTop + $(node).height();

    return ((nodeBottom >= docViewTop) && (nodeTop <= docViewBottom)
      && (nodeBottom <= docViewBottom) &&  (nodeTop >= docViewTop) );
}
```

CSS:

```
#urlEdit.floating {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

straight from [from the jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/show/):

> With no parameters, the .show() method is the simplest way to display
>   an element:
>
> $('.target').show();
>
> The matched elements will be revealed immediately, with no animation.
>   This is roughly equivalent to calling .css('display', 'block'), except
>   that the display property is restored to whatever it was initially. If
>   an element has a display value of inline, then is hidden and shown, it
>   will once again be displayed inline.

the best way in this situation is, imo, to create a class, a corresponding css rule, and use addClass/removeClass instead of show/hide.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't like the way this is functioning, you can always write your own show/hide plugins with your own custom logic applied.  Put this code in your JavaScript:

```
$.fn.extend({
  myShow: function() {
    return this.css('display','block');
  }, 
  myHide: function() {
    return this.css('display', 'none');
  }
});
```